# Cordova write PNG in storage from canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

Does somebody know if it is possible to write PNG/JPG images using Cordova pugin?

*Just file plugin, no other plugins.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html